# How to specify a model in a default_scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, scope

My model `Chapter` has_many `Pages`, which in turn belong_to only one `Chapter`.  I'm trying to do the following joins:

```
Chapter.joins(:pages)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: SELECT "chapters".* FROM "chapters" INNER JOIN "pages" ON "pages"."chapter_id" = "chapters"."id" AND (created_at >= '2015-04-24 23:22:32.783941')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: SELECT "chapters".* FROM "chapters" INNER JOIN "pages" ON "pages"."chapter_id" = "chapters"."id" AND (created_at >= '2015-04-24 23:22:32.783941')
```

`Page` has the following default scope:

```
default_scope { where('created_at >= ?', 7.days.ago) }
```

and without that default_scope, the joins works. So I think that somehow I have to specify `page.created_at` in the default_scope. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
default_scope {
  where("pages.created_at >= ?", 7.days.ago)
}
```